# Spring: what does getBean method do?

Tags: java, spring

I was reading the following article: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-autowired-annotation-example-with-setter-method-field-and-constructor-using-xml-and-java-configuration

and I found there the following code snippet:

```
package com.concretepage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.concretepage.bean.Company;
import com.concretepage.bean.Employee;
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Company getCompany() {
        Company company = new Company();
        company.setCompName("ABCD Ltd");
        company.setLocation("Varanasi");
        return company;
    }
    @Bean
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return new Employee();
    }
} 



package com.concretepage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import com.concretepage.bean.Employee;
public class SpringDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
       ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
       ctx.refresh();
       Employee employee = ctx.getBean(Employee.class);
       System.out.println("Company Name:"+ employee.getCompany().getCompName());
       System.out.println("Location:"+ employee.getCompany().getLocation());
       ctx.close();
   }
}
```

I want to get an explanation about the line:

```
       Employee employee = ctx.getBean(Employee.class);
```

'ctx' gets AppConfig class as an argument. AppConfig class includes two methods getCompany and getEmployee. What I don't understand is that if we have the method 'getEmployee' that returns a new 'Employee' object, why do we have to use 'ctx.getBean(Employee.class)' to do the same thing?

Also, what is the benefit from using the annotation '@Bean' on methods 'getCompany' and 'getEmployee'?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Bean` annotation is used by Spring's ApplicationContext to create the beans which are returned. By default only 1 instance is created. Beans are singletons.

Using `Employee employee = ctx.getBean(Employee.class);` returns the same Object every times you call it.

So to answer your questions:

1. **If we have the method 'getEmployee' that returns a new 'Employee' object, why do we have to use 'ctx.getBean(Employee.class)'?**
   Because that is the way Spring's Application Context initializes the Beans. It runs your `getEmployee()` method and creates a Bean.
2. **What is the benefit from using the annotation '@Bean' on methods 'getCompany' and 'getEmployee'?**
   Well, if you don't use `@Bean` Spring doesn't know that you want a Bean.

And yes.. reading some Spring documentation goes a long way.

Answer (score -1):

About benefits of using @Bean: Take a look on it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

D.I. (Dependency injection) concept is what you need to understand first, and than you will be able to see how these @Beans can be used/injected.